# Makefile:21: *** recipe commences before first target. Stop

Tags: makefile

I was trying to build a make file to load a plugin from snap telemetry...when I was trying with the command `sudo make build` it is showing `Makefile:21: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.` this error....In make file I added

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=/home/intel/Downloads/snap-tele/gopath
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/intel/Downloads/snap-tele/gopath/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide
echo $PATH
```

My make file looks like below when I do `cat -e -t -v Makefile` where ^I shows tab space and $ represents end of line

```
^Iexport GOROOT=/usr/local/go$
^Iexport GOPATH=/home/intel/Downloads/snap-tele/gopath$
^Iexport PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/intel/Downloads/snap-tele/gopath/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide$
^Iecho $PATH$
$
default:$
^I$(MAKE) deps$
^I$(MAKE) all$
deps:$
^Ibash -c "./scripts/deps.sh"$
test:$
^Ibash -c "./scripts/test.sh $(TEST_TYPE)"$
test-legacy:$
^Ibash -c "./scripts/test.sh legacy"$
test-small:$
^Ibash -c "./scripts/test.sh small"$
test-medium:$
^Ibash -c "./scripts/test.sh medium"$
test-large:$
^Ibash -c "./scripts/test.sh large"$
test-all:$
^I$(MAKE) test-small$
^I$(MAKE) test-medium$
^I$(MAKE) test-large$
check:$
^I$(MAKE) test$
all:$
^Ibash -c "./scripts/build.sh"$
$
```

Where might be the problem?..as per my knowledge I have given correct tab places..

Answer (score 1):

A few things:  First, make expects targets/recipe's in the form of:

```
target: [deps...]
<tab> recipe 1
<tab> recipe 2
```

And it will run the recipes if and only if the target needs to be rebuilt.  You don't specify a target, but you do specify lines that start with tabs (recipes).   Make is complaining that you have recipes without a target (as it should).

However, that being said, it does not appear as though you want your lines to be run as part of a recipe (it wouldn't work anyways, as exported variables are not remembered from one recipe line to another, let alone between targets).

You likely want to do:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=/home/intel/Downloads/snap-tele/gopath
export PATH:=${PATH}:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/intel/Downloads/snap-tele/gopath/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide
$(info PATH=${PATH})
```

without any preceding tabs.   The lack of tabs means that make will interpret the commands as part of the makefile interpreter in the make parsing stage.   Notice that `echo` is a shell command, which make does not understand, so I replaced it with make's `$(info ... )` which is equivalent.

Edit: Sorry, I missed the access to `$PATH` -- Make would interpret this as `$P` followed by the literal `ATH`.   You should use `${PATH}` in this case.   You should also use `:=` instead of `=` to avoid recursive assignments (see https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC59)

Comment: [`export`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Quick-Reference.html) is a make-directive that makes available the exported variable to all child processes, specifically sub-makes. The OP evidently confuses it with shell `export`, but it's likely fit for the intended purpose.

Comment: The make `export` directive also allows the shell to access the variable.   Thus `export XX:=yy` followed by `all:; echo $$XX` will output `yy`.

Comment: (Though I just checked, and can't confirm this will work on older, or non-gnu makes)

Comment: I tried everything what you people told...but still it is same error

Comment: what version of make are you using (`make --version`)?